# Generating a code coverage report with PHPUnit

Tags: php, testing, xdebug

Does anyone know the correct command line to generate a code coverage file on a PHP project? I've already installed the XDebug tool.

In the official documentation from PHPUnit, I found the following command line, but it is not working:

```
phpunit --coverage-text=<file>
```

where  is the file where output is going to be stored.

I don't have any tests yet, but is there a way to generate a report file, even though there are no tests in the project?

Comment: Hello @GrumpyCrouton! Hope now it is more clear.

Comment: It is much better, except you should explain what you mean by "it is not working"; how is it not working?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to include the path to your tests, as well as the white list command with the path to the source code to be tested. E.g.

```
phpunit --coverage-text="coverage.txt" ./path/to/tests --whitelist="./path/to/code"
```

Where coverage.txt is the file that the output will be stored in. You can generate a report without any tests.